# tfs build number - getting started

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I have Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer. After I check in code, I can view the changeset number (View History). 
I typically put in the Changeset number in the bug log system as soon as I fix something. 
Now where/how do I get the build number? Is this a TFS admin thing? Where do I get started? Do I need to use MSBuild instead of using Visual Studio GUI?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

When [creating a build definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413265.aspx), by default TFS labels each build with this format: `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`

The Default Template's build number can be customized under
`[build defintion]` > `Process` > `Basic` > `Build Number Format`

However, you may want to check out [Versioned TFS 2010 Build](http://versionedtfsbuild.codeplex.com/) for more control over the build number format and automatic versioning of the assemblies (via AssemblyInfo.cs).

Comment: I'm a total newbie at doing this. I just use Build Solution from the GUI to build the projects. WHere is this option in the GUI? I went to Team Explorer, found the Builds menu item but there is only one item in there  - All Build Definitions. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Create a build defintion first. [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/01/19/tfs-2010-the-new-build-definition-window.aspx) may help.

Answer (score 0):

through gui:

right click on builds > view builds > tab to "completed"

build definition > all
quality filter > all
date filter > today

double click on the build of interest:

you should see the build number and changeset at the very top.

=========

When you commit you should use the dialog to associate your commit to a work item - this way you don't have to manually set any of this.

To get these details in msbuild the data can be retrieved using:

```
    <Exec Condition=" '$(IsInTeamBuild)'=='True'" Command="&quot;$(TfsTask)&quot; history ../ /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W > &quot;$(TemporaryFolder)\grab-changeset.txt&quot;" />
    <Exec Condition=" '$(IsInTeamBuild)'=='True'" Command="&quot;$(TfsTask)&quot; properties &quot;$(MyMSBuildStartupDirectory)\all-companies-run-after-update.js&quot; > &quot;$(TemporaryFolder)\grab-properties.txt&quot;" />
```

we use the above to extract: build#, branch, revision#

Comment: I don't see any builds listed in the Completed/Queued tabs. Looks like there are no builds setup yet (?). I tried to create a new build definition but got a Permission Denied error. I'll talk to the admin and report back. Will there be options to set custom build number when I try to create the new build through the UI? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend signing up for: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/ Team Foundation Build 2010 Introduction

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't set up a TFS-build at all.
Even though this will require some time to grasp as a concept & tailor a solution to your own needs, this is definitely worth the investment (or, the other way around, NOT using TFS build makes the whole investment into TFS a lot less worth it).
[This](http://www.theabsentmindedcoder.com/2010/02/creating-my-first-tfs-2010-build.html) might be a nice starting point, there are a lot of useful resources out there, I 'd advise you to take a deep breath and dive right in. You can always return with more specific questions.